# Use JavaScript to rewrite CSS with class and tag at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am able to easily change the style or the tag of an element based on certain criteria using JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("mainclass")[0].style.color:#ffffff;
```

However, is there a way to do this is the style contains multiple classes and a tag like so

```
.mainclass .secondaryclass div td {
color: #000000;
}
```

The following is not working for me so im sure there is a totally different way of doing it:

```
document.getElementsByTagName(".mainclass .secondaryclass div td")[0].style.color:#ffffff;
```

...

The other option if easier is to figure out how to use JS to embbed a external style sheet (and not at the end of head, just where the JS code is thats where the CSS should go)

Thanks!

Comment: `.color:#ffffff` should be `.color=#ffffff`

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementsByTagName) does not accept CSS selector syntax. You're looking for [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) but you'll have to iterate over the returned list to assign the style, and [it's not *completely* supported across browsers.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll#Browser_compatibility)

...which is why everyone uses jQuery.

Example, assuming you want to modify just the first matched element:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".mainclass .secondaryclass div td")[0].style.color = '#ffffff';
```

Note the change from `:` to `=`, and wrapping the color value in quotes. JavaScript has different syntax from CSS; I suggest that you take some time to learn it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think this is something I will look into as I cant test it right away since it doesn't look like it can be added inside JS code: <script> 

if (/newpage/.test(self.location.href)) { 

document.querySelectorAll("login_wrapper .login_form_wrapper table td")[0].style.color = '#ffffff'; 
} 

</script>